# How does `cat <> file` work?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

`cat < file` prints the contents of *file* to stdout.

`cat > file` reads stdin until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is detected and the input text is written to *file*.

`cat <> file`, at least in my version of Bash, prints the contents of *file* happily (without error), but doesn't modify the file nor does it update the modification timestamp.

How does the Bash standard justify the seemingly ignored `>` in the third statement - and, more importantly, is it **doing** anything?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Bash uses `<>` to create [a read-write file descriptor](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Opening-File-Descriptors-for-Reading-and-Writing):

> The redirection operator
>
> ```
> [n]<>word
> ```
>
> causes the file whose name is the expansion of word to be opened for both reading and writing on file descriptor n, or on file descriptor 0 if n is not specified. If the file does not exist, it is created.

`cat <> file` opens `file` read-write and binds it to descriptor 0 (standard input). It's essentially equivalent to `< file` for any sensibly-written program, since nobody's likely to try writing to standard input ordinarily, but if one did it'd be able to.

You can write a simple C program to test that out directly - `write(0, "hello", 6)` will write `hello` into `file` via standard input.

`<>` should [also work in any other POSIX-compliant shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_07) with the same effect.

Comment: Writing... to stdin?... Is there any *valid* use case for this?

Comment: Off-hand, I can't think of any good one. Giving an explicit descriptor (`4<>file`) is useful, and I suppose 0 is as good a default as any when you leave it out. Reading from stdout isn't any better.

Comment: While reading from stdout is generally not useful, `1<> the-file` often is as it also does not truncate the-file. `<>` was introduced by the Bourne shell, so would work in any Bourne-like shell.

Comment: `<>` is also useful on some systems (like Linux) to open named pipes without blocking until another process opens it for writing.

Comment: @Qix: Well write(0, "Password: ", 10) is a good way to prompt for a password if you intend to prompt on anything kind of like a tty. I'm used to seeing it only on stderr but no reason in particular the same technique doesn't work on stdin.

Comment: @Joshua, a couple of reasons why it may not be a good idea: tty devices don't _have_ to be open in read+write mode. If you do that, you'd still want to check stdin is a terminal (and you might as well do a `open("/dev/tty")`. That prevents users from disabling it (by using `2> /dev/null`) (with `open("/dev/tty")` as well though).

Comment: I use some indirect connections for which open("/dev/tty") will fail because it's not really a tty but writing to stdin or stderr works just fine.

Comment: So I suppose my question in response to all of this; is there anything special about FD 0/1/2? Or is it just convention that 0=stdin, 1=stdout, etc.?

Comment: @Qix: `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` file descriptors must be 0, 1 and 2 respectively when a program starts: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stdin.html

Comment: @Qix - from the [POSIX Rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html) - The `<>` operator could be useful in writing an application that worked with several terminals, and occasionally wanted to start up a shell. That shell would in turn be unable to run applications that run from an ordinary controlling terminal unless it could make use of `<>` ... such as ... the pager `more`, which reads from standard error to get its commands, so standard input and standard output are both available for their usual usage. 
`cat food | more - >/dev/tty03 2<>/dev/tty03`

Comment: <>file exists since the first Bourne Shell in 1978 so it is not a POSIX thing. UNIX opes the default file descriptors 0, 1, 2 for reading and writing and some programs expect to be able to read fom stderr or to write to stdin. This is why <> exists.

Comment: @schily, however [as noted by Sven Mascheck](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/), it was initially undocumented and broken there (confirmed with v7 on a pdp11 emulator). Not fixed on SunOS before 5.6. BSD shells (based on ash) didn't have a `<>` until quite late for some.

Comment: You  seem to be correct, the files have been always opened either readonly or writeonly, so there was a bug in the interpreter part that did not implement all features understood by the parser. Fixed in 1997...

Answer (score 51):

`<> file` opens the file (on file descriptor 0 (stdin) by default, like `<`) in **read+write** mode **without truncation** and **creating the file if it didn't exist beforehand**.

That corresponds to the `O_RDWR|O_CREAT` flags passed to the `open()` system call. By contrast `<` is `O_RDONLY` and `>` is `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC` and `>>` `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND`.

Having stdin writable is not often useful as applications usually don't write to their stdin. Applications usually don't expect to read *and* write on a file descriptor they receive on startup; they usually read from stdin (or a file descriptor they open themselves) and write to stdout or stderr (or a file descriptor they open themselves).

`<>` can have its uses:

- You may prefer `cat <> file` over `cat < file` if you don't want the command to fail if `file` doesn't exist, but an empty `file` created instead.
- The non-truncating aspect of `<>` makes it useful to overwrite files in place. In that case however, you generally don't use it on file descriptor 0:

  ```
  printf xxx 1<> file
  ```

  replaces the first 3 bytes of `file` with `xxx`.
- On some systems like Linux, `<>` on a named pipe (FIFO) opens the named pipe without blocking (without waiting for some other process to open the other end), and ensures the pipe structure is left alive. For instance in:

  ```
  mkfifo pipe; sed 's/foo/bar/g' <> pipe
  ```

  `sed` handles incoming data from any number of other processes writing to it and never sees `eof`.

Comment: Note that on AT&T ksh93, `<>` defaults to `1<>` (stdout) instead of `0<>` (stdin). This is a POSIX compliance bug which I reported and will be fixed in the next release. https://github.com/att/ast/issues/75 But until current ksh93 versions fall out of use, you have to include the file descriptor number to use `<>` portably.

Comment: @MartijnDekker, I know, I was the one telling you about it in the first place ;-). Note that it's only for ksh93t+ (where the behaviour changed) and above.

Comment: What are (or were) the systems *unlike* Linux where `mkfifo fifo; exec 3<>fifo` would block?

Comment: @UncleBilly, I wouldn't remember. POSIX leaves it undefined if you open a fifo with O_RDWR.