# How to read from a named pipe after the writer process exits?

Tags: shell, zsh, pipe, nohup, fifo

I want to use named pipes as asynchrnonous task queues (JMS-like, perhaps).

For example, suppose a client sends some data that I wish to insert into a database, but I want the client to disconnect from the server immediately and the server process pipe the data into a named pipe. Then completely independently read the data from the pipe and perform a SQL insert, which might be very slow - but the client doesn't notice because it gets a response immediately.

As a prototype, I thought this would work (for simplicity the "45" is echoed rather than sent through a netcat client-server pair):

```
zsh> nohup echo "45" > my_named_pipe &
zsh> exit
zsh: warning: 1 jobs SIGHUPed
```

Then much later, execute

```
zsh> cat my_named_pipe
```

But nothing comes out of the pipe. What's wrong with my setup?

PS: I've never got `nohup` to work. I always rely on `disown` which I don't want to do as a separate command in this scenario.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What version of bash do you have?

Comment: I'm actually using `zsh 5.0.2` (though I wrote "bash" above). What happens when you do it? What version of bash do you use? If it works for you I should try that out myself.

Comment: Oh, it works for me with bash. So zsh is to blame?

Comment: I'd say bash is to blame for not cleaning up its children when it gets a SIGHUP but if you want to look at it another way I can't stop you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
nohup echo "45" > my_named_pipe &
```

The shell forks itself. In the child, it opens `my_named_pipe` for writing. That `open()` blocks until something else opens `my_named_pipe` for reading.

When you run `exit` in the parent process, the child is still blocked on the `open()` and has not executed `nohup` yet.

So upon exiting you shell, the shell sends SIGHUP to the child, which it doesn't ignore since it has not run `nohup` yet.

Just run:

```
(echo 45 > my_named_pipe &)
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
echo 45 > my_named_pipe &!
```

`&!` is zsh syntactic sugar for `disown`

> Both BASH and ZSH have a nice builtin called disown. It enables user
>   to detach process from the shell in a way much similar to that of
>   nohup. ZSH has a nice sugar for it: you can put &! at the end of the
>   command, and it would be detached. BASH doesn’t have such sugar
>
> http://blog.debiania.in.ua/posts/2013-03-13-fun-with-bash-disown.html

Comment: Good information. But the zsh one doesn't work. Is this a drop-in replacement for my command? Or do I need to do something else differently?

Comment: Ooops, ignore that last post. It works. Thank you :)

Comment: Is the `<>` redirect that you mention [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164449/52934) not also applicable here?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having, and the reason it's shell-dependent, is that the `>` redirection is processed first, and if nobody is reading the pipe yet, it will block. Only after the open succeeds will the shell execute `nohup`. You disconnected while it was still blocked in open, so `nohup` hadn't happened yet and the `SIGHUP` killed the background process. This is why `disown` is better. It applies to the job immediately.

From my attempt at reproducing the problem with bash, it seems that bash doesn't relay the session-ending SIGHUP to its children like zsh does, so the background job survives.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Good to know `disown` is a good solution. Is there any way to use disown "inline" like nohup? Looking at the manpages it doesn't appear so :(

Comment: Answer to my own followup question: `&!`